# Can someone explain why this LINQ-to-entitiy query causes an error, and why my solution fixes it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

The expression that is thrown is:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of
> type 'CantShowYouThis'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are
> supported in this context.'

Query that causes an error

```
context.tableA.RemoveRange(context.tableA.Where(conflict => listOfCantShowYouThis.Select(r => 
r.Id).Contains(conflict.RequestId)));
```

Solution:

```
var list = listOfCantShowYouThis.Select(r => r.Id);
context.tableA.RemoveRange(context.tableA.Where(conflict => list.Contains(conflict.RequestId)));
```

This code is taken from the codebase I'm working with, so I've had to remove the names of classes and such just to stay on the safe side.

From googling a bit I think it is related to the mixing of in-memory data and database data which EF / LINQ-to-entity doesn't like. I might be wrong, but even if I'm not, it is still a very shallow understanding of what is going on. I'd like to understand why my fix works. I know that doing Select won't really do much until it is actually used (by calling ToList() or some other method), because of deferred execution so it strange to me that moving it like this solves the problem.

Comment: Is `CantShowYouThis` the type of `listOfObject` and if so you should change it to `List<CantShowThis>` otherwise it's hard to *guess* at what your actual error is

Comment: listOfObject is of type List<CantShowYouThis>
I will update my question to clearify this, I could have done a better job there

Comment: Is this EF or EFCore?

Comment: We're using EF version 6.1.3